# Need to add missing value from pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I've two pandas dataframe having one common column in both but they are not having same values. Wish to get the missing values to another dataframe common column.

```
df1

name    mobile  email
abcd    992293  abcd@abcd.com
efgh    687678  efgh@efgh.com
ijkl    7878678 ijkl@ijkl.com
mnop    678687  mnop@mnop.com
qrst    6876    qrst@qrst.com
```

```
df2

name    age
abcd    22
efgh    12
```

```
Expected output

name    age
abcd    22
efgh    12
ijkl
mnop
qrst
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple case of joining two data frames on a common key:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on='name',how='left')
```